# Fetching column values from result of case expression in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table with columns PRNumber, PRLevel, Levelstatus and TransDate

Executed the following case expression,

**Firstcase:**

```
 select PRNumber,PRLevel,Levelstatus,Trasdate, 
    case when Levelstatus = 'PUR' 
    then prlevel - 1 
    end as [PR_level] 
from dbo.tblpr_approvalstatus where prnumber = '000005'
```

```
PRNumber    PRLevel Levelstatus Trasdate                  PR_Level
000005      1       DM          2015-06-15 10:07:33.467   NULL
000005      2       PRE         2015-06-15 11:09:08.980   NULL
000005      4       IMM         2015-06-19 12:02:56.600   NULL
000005      5       PUR         2015-06-19 14:37:43.650   4
000005      3       FIN         2015-06-18 21:07:57.933   NULL
```

When Levelstatus is equal to PUR, I get the PrLevel  5 from case expression, I want to fetch the Trasdate of previous value of PRlevel in the case expression like as below

**Secondcase:**

```
select case when PRlevel = 4 
then trasdate 
end as [Transaction_date] 
from tblpr_approvalstatus where prnumber = '000005'
```

I want to combine first case and second case expression as a single expression to fetch the Trasdate column values when Levelstatus = ‘PUR’ and previous value of PRLevel.

The columns PRLevel, Levelstatus and TransDate are having different values for each PRNumber.

Comment: Which version of sql server you are using ??

Comment: I am using sql server 2005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like below,

```
    SELECT PRNumber
     ,PRLevel
     ,Levelstatus
     ,Trasdate
     ,CASE 
     WHEN Levelstatus='PUR' THEN prlevel- 1
       END  AS [PR_level]
      ,(
           SELECT Trasdate
           FROM   tblpr_approvalstatus TAS
           WHERE  TAS.prnumber = tblpr_approvalstatus.prnumber
                  AND TAS.prlevel = CASE 
                                        WHEN tblpr_approvalstatus.Levelstatus='PUR' THEN 
                                             tblpr_approvalstatus.prlevel 
                                            - 1
                                   END
       )    AS Prev
FROM   tblpr_approvalstatus
WHERE  prnumber = '000005'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! #SOReadyToHelp BTW, if you upvote my post you will get a Bronze 'Supporter' badge for your first upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Add the expression:

( SELECT Trasdate FROM tblpr_approvalstatus a2 where a2.prnumber = a1.prnumber and a2.prlevel = case when a1.Levelstatus = 'PUR' 
    then a1.prlevel - 1 
    end ) AS prev

Note - add a table alias of a1 to your existing table on the from clause.